# pandas.df.columns - making output for visually useful

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a pandas df. Simple question, I hope:

pandas.df.columns returns an index with the column names of the df, separated by columns in a list. Example: `Index(['a, 'c, 'c, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g', 'h'],dtype='object')`

I'd like the above in a vertical output (a would row 1, b row 2, etc.)

QUESTION: Is there more visually appealing way to return a list of column names, for instance with each column name in a separate row?

e.g. maybe each column name in a row vs separated by a comma in a run on list? Thanks.

Basically: something like pandas.df.dtypes but without the data types in the second column.  I'd like it to return 'a' on row 1, 'b' on row 2, etc. I just want to the output to be more visually presentable vs everything running together.  I hope that make sense. Thank you.

Comment: can you post your output too.

Comment: You can convert it to series, pd.Series(df.columns)

Comment: great, exactly what i was looking for. thank you Vaishali

Comment: df.columns
>>>Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd, 'e,
       ‘f, 'g, ‘h’,
      dtype='object')


What I want (or something similar, where columns are displayed vertically in rows)
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
dtype=’object
* note, pd.Series(df.columns) gives me what I was looking for (thanks Vaishali)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `.values` to `df.columns` you get a numpy ndarray, which gives you the option of iterating over its positions with a `for` loop.

```
for col in df.columns.values:
    print(col)
```